# Checking IFI enabled on SQL server below 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

I am using in one of my reports to check for status of IFI being enabled on SQL server.

It works well when using dmv `sys.dm_server_service`s for SQL2016

However, in SQL2014 and SQL2012 i see difficulties in rendering this check via SQL query.

For example if i use below

```
EXEC sys.xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, N'Database Instant File Initialization';
```

There is no guarantee it will show status on file '0' and sometimes i keep querying the error log manually to find that out. How can i achieve the IFI check using a better way so that it can show up on my SSRS report

Comment: I haven’t actually tested this but the post uses PowerShell to check if the specified user account has been granted the local policy “Perform Volume Maintenance Tasks”.  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5240/scripts-to-check-sql-server-instant-file-initialization-and-lock-pages-in-memory-for-all-servers/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this MSSQLTips.com article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5136/check-sql-server-instant-file-initialization-for-all-servers/), you can use `sys.dm_server_services` beginning with SQL 2012 SP4.

> ```
> SELECT  @@SERVERNAME AS [Server Name] ,
>         RIGHT(@@version, LEN(@@version) - 3 - CHARINDEX(' ON ', @@VERSION)) AS [OS Info] ,
>         LEFT(@@VERSION, CHARINDEX('-', @@VERSION) - 2) + ' '
>         + CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS NVARCHAR(300)) AS [SQL Server Version] ,
>         service_account ,
>         instant_file_initialization_enabled
> FROM    sys.dm_server_services
> WHERE   servicename LIKE 'SQL Server (%'
> ```

For older versions, you'll need to scrape the log, looking for "Database Instant File Initialization: enabled."

Answer (score 4):

Glenn Spies posted at SQLSkills.com this script.
https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/how-to-tell-if-you-have-instant-initialization-enabled/

I've used it a few times, and it works correctly.

```
USE master
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;
GO

CREATE TABLE #xp_cmdshell_output (Output VARCHAR (8000));
GO

INSERT INTO #xp_cmdshell_output EXEC ('xp_cmdshell ''whoami /priv''');
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #xp_cmdshell_output WHERE Output LIKE '%SeManageVolumePrivilege%')
PRINT 'Instant Initialization enabled'
ELSE
PRINT 'Instant Initialization disabled';
GO

DROP TABLE #xp_cmdshell_output;
GO

EXEC sp_configure ‘xp_cmdshell’, 0;
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;
GO
EXEC sp_configure ‘show advanced options’, 0
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;
GO
```

Comment: This is pretty neat, and I'm leveraging it. It does require `xp_cmdshell`, though that seems a non-issue with the OP's current usage of `xp_readerrorlog`.

Comment: @Conrad please add small script to change `xp_cmdshell` run value to 0 at the end of the script, please note you enabled it in the beginning.

Comment: @Shanky,  I added those lines.  Thanks.  They were in the original.